# SignalR client undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, signalr

I've this front-code to do the update of the table as soon is updated in the sql table.
But i can't find a way to solve this problem.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Proxy created on the fly
        var job = $.connection.DataHub;
        console.log(job);
        // Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke it
        job.client.displayStatus = function () {
            getData();
        };

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();
        getData();
    });

    function getData() {
        var $tbl = $('#tblJobInfo');
        $.ajax({
            url: '../api/values',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $tbl.empty();
                    $tbl.append(' <tr><th>ID</th><th>Titulo</th>/tr>');
                    var rows = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        rows.push(' <tr><td>' + data[i].Id + '</td><td>' + data[i].titulo + '</td></tr>');
                    }
                    $tbl.append(rows.join(''));
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

How can this be solved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is you didn't change the hub's name to camel case. See below:

```
 var job = $.connection.dataHub;
```

If you use a HubName attribute, there is no name change to camel case on JavaScript clients:

```
[HubName("DataHub")]
public class DataHub: Hub
```

Also if you're using ASP.NET MVC 4 or 5 Razor view, use the tilde to refer to the application root in your proxy file reference:

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Comment: i did this now, but same problem

Answer (score 0):

We were getting the same error but, in our case we had one deployment on Windows Server 2008 IIS 7 (and it worked without errors) and another one (same app, same code) on Windows Server IIS 8 (raised the same error as the original poster).

Our solution was to modify the web.config and comment out the "system.webServer" section in the location section for signalr/hubs when deploying on IIS 8.

(note system.webServer is commented)

```
<location path="signalr/hubs"> 
    <system.web> 
        <authorization> 
            <allow users="*"/> 
        </authorization> 
    </system.web> 
    <!--system.webServer> 
        <security> 
            <authorization> 
                <add accessType="Allow" users="*"/> 
            </authorization> 
        </security> 
    </system.webServer--> 
</location>
```

This is the original and it works on IIS 7, but fails on IIS 8:

(note system.webServer is not commented)

```
<location path="signalr/hubs"> 
    <system.web> 
        <authorization> 
            <allow users="*"/> 
        </authorization> 
    </system.web> 
    <system.webServer> 
        <security> 
            <authorization> 
                <add accessType="Allow" users="*"/> 
            </authorization> 
        </security> 
    </system.webServer> 
</location>
```